# repository sync from bitbucket to github as a backup repository

Tags: github, synchronization, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am looking for a solution to create a synced backup repo from bitbucket to github . I am using bitbucket pipelines for it and it is working fine for me but when there is a file more than 100MB in size I get lfs error in bitbucket pipelines.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml working conf for below 100MB files.

```
clone:
  depth: full  
  
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git push git@github.com:gitusername/repo.git
```

bitbucket pipelines Error :

```
+ git push git@github.com:gitusername/repo.git
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.255.112' to the list of known hosts.
remote: error: Trace: fa16206af988931f97f89bfbe89e0a6d7e0373ea332e8112612d6224b4de354c        
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.        
remote: error: File VMware.bundle is 167.19 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: File wps.deb is 262.46 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.        
To git@github.com:gitusername/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:gitusername/repo.git'
```

Comment: there is a mirror plugin in bitbucket that can do what you want.

Comment: how can I use that plugin? we are not using bitbucket server we are working from bitbucket website.

Comment: apparently your error is not really about the sync. but about github refusing to store big files as plain objects. and it says you have to use LFS. Try to google on github lfs and what you can do about it.